# jQuery scrollTop not scrolling to last-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a chat system. What I would like to have happen is when the div begins overflow, force it to stay on the last

element. I have tried several suggestions from other questions on here, and still cannot get it to work. Within the #chat-area i am using ajax to display a chat.txt file. When you type text into the #sendie textarea and press enter, it appends the chat.txt file with the text you entered. Each entry into the chat.txt tthen has a `<p>` tag automatically added to it. So I need it to just stay on the last `<p>`

Here is where I'm at currently:

HTML:

```
<div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

<form id="send-message-area">
    <p>Your message: </p>
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '200' ></textarea>
</form>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chatWrap').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#chat-area p:last-child').position().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
#chatWrap
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #333 inset;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
overflow: auto;
}

#chat-area
{
padding-left: 11px;
}

#chat-area p:nth-child(even)
{
background: #961B10;
margin-left: -8px;
padding-left: 14px;
padding-top: 9px;
padding-bottom: 9px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

EDIT:

The following is the output:

```
<div id="chatWrap">
    <div id="chat-area">
        <p>Guest:hi </p>
        <p>Guest:hello </p>
        <p>Guest:Hey </p>
        <p>Guest:Hi </p>
        <p>Guest:Hello </p>
        <p>Guest:Hey </p>
        <p>Guest:Hi </p>
    </div>
</div>
<form id="send-message-area">
    <p>Your message: </p>
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength="200"></textarea>
</form>
```

The following is the AJAX:

```
var instanse = false;
var state;
var mes;
var file;

function Chat () {
    this.update = updateChat;
    this.send = sendChat;
    this.getState = getStateOfChat;
}

//gets the state of the chat
function getStateOfChat(){
if(!instanse){
     instanse = true;
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "process.php",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'getState',
                    'file': file
                    },
           dataType: "json",

           success: function(data){
               state = data.state;
               instanse = false;
           },
        });
}    
}

//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
 if(!instanse){
     instanse = true;
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "process.php",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'update',
                    'state': state,
                    'file': file
                    },
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               if(data.text){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++)          {
                        $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
                    }                                 
               }
               document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop =        document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
               instanse = false;
               state = data.state;
           },
        });
 }
 else {
     setTimeout(updateChat, 3000);
 }
}

//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname)
{       
updateChat();
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "process.php",
       data: {  
                'function': 'send',
                'message': message,
                'nickname': nickname,
                'file': file
             },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
           updateChat();
       },
    });
}
```

process.php:

```
<?php

$function = $_POST['function'];

$log = array();

switch($function) {

     case('getState'):
         if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $log['state'] = count($lines); 
         break; 

     case('update'):
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $count =  count($lines);
         if($state == $count){
             $log['state'] = $state;
             $log['text'] = false;

             }
             else{
                 $text= array();
                 $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
                 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
                   {
                       if($line_num >= $state){
                     $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                       }

                    }
                 $log['text'] = $text; 
             }

         break;

     case('send'):
      $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
         $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
          $message =($_POST['message']);
     if(($message) != "\n"){

         if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
            $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
            } 


         fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), "". $nickname . ":" . $message = str_replace("\n", " ", $message) . "\n"); 
     }
         break;

}

echo json_encode($log);

?>
```

Script in header:

```
// strip tags
    name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

    // display name on page
    $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");

    // kick off chat
    var chat =  new Chat();
    $(function() {

         chat.getState(); 

         // watch textarea for key presses
         $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  

             var key = event.which;  

             //all keys including return.  
             if (key >= 33) {

                 var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                 var length = this.value.length;  

                 // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                 if (length >= maxLength) {  
                     event.preventDefault();  
                 }  
              }  
});
         // watch textarea for release of key press
         $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   

              if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                var text = $(this).val();
                var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                var length = text.length; 

                // send 
                if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 

                    chat.send(text, name);  
                    $(this).val("");

                } else {

                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                }   


              }
         });

    });
```

Edit AGAIN:

So I have discovered where the error is.

```
// kick off chat
    var chat =  new Chat();
ERROR: Chat is not defined
    $(function() {
```

Comment: and why not posting relevant HTML code? BTW, you should provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Could you send a more complete HTML code with #chatWrap, #chat-area and #chat-area p?

Comment: Sorry somehow the formatting got messed up. Fixed it.

Comment: Keep in mind, within the #chat-area div is where ajax is displaying my chat.txt file. Each line is in a <p> tag

Comment: Could you provide real code font with paragraphs, like, after load the content? I can't see any problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/qB3m7/

Comment: @Leo I have edited my original question to show the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this function:

```
$('#chatWrap').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#chat-area').height()
}, 1000);
})
```

Check this demo based on the fiddle of @Leo **http://jsfiddle.net/qB3m7/4/**

Comment: After implementing this, the text area i enter the text in will not let me send anymore.

Comment: Can you reproduce that behavior in the fiddle?

Comment: Ok maybe I should have been more clear. The #sendie textarea is used to send the input to the chat.txt file. The way I have it now is when you press enter after entering text into the text area, it sends it. In your fiddle, the textarea #sendie isn't doing anything. I guess I was also unclear in the fact that when entering the text into the #sendie textarea it adds <p> tags automatically to the text when appending it into the chat.txt

Comment: @Aldentec I believe the problem is just when this functions is being fired. It must be right after you load the content into #chat-area. Could you provide your ajax function that does it?

Comment: @Aldentec I know the text is send from the text box I only made the link to simulate the addition of a `p` tag i believe you already have the function for the text area...

Answer (score 1):

You could try change your updateChat() function, on sucess to be like this:

```
   success: function(data){
       if(data.text){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++)          {
                $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
            }
                $('#chatWrap').animate({
                   scrollTop: $('#chat-area').height()
                   }, 1000);
                })               
       }
       document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop =        document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
       instanse = false;
       state = data.state;
   },
```

What does this line do? `document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop =        document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;` I guess you won't need it. Comment it before try this update.

Comment: Hey I added this, the problem is now when i enter text into #sendie, and press enter, it goes to the next line rather than sending it like it did before. Any idea why this code change would affect that?

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Are you getting any error on Javascript Console?

Comment: Yes actually:

    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } chat.js:55
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Chat is not defined index.php:22
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined

Comment: It shouldn't affect it, but what if you force sending when press enter with this code? `$('#sendie').keydown(function(e) {     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#send-message-area').submit();
   }
});`

Comment: I didn't think when I originally asked the question that this code would be needed, but I was wrong. SO I updated my question to include the script i have in my header.php

Comment: Where are you getting the error now? Do you have your system working online?

Comment: Still getting the same errors. When you mentioned the keydown function for #sendie is when I figured I would add that code since it already existed. And yes I do have it online, however requires a login.

Comment: Your `$("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {` is not being closed with `}` in header.php

Comment: somehow again the formatting got messed up for that. It is there now how I believe it is supposed to be.

Comment: I updated my original post to show where an error is popping up.

Comment: You will have to declare the Chat function or call the JS Chat file before declare `var chat =  new Chat();`

Comment: Would including   <script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
 
do the trick?

Comment: Yes! And probably it will require you to add jquery.js, so chat.js and then you declare `var chat = new Chat();`.

Answer (score 0):

@Leo I have updated to include the ajax plus the process.php code