# Scroll to the Bottom of Dynamic Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with id "page-content", it does not have **height** or **width**, it just have a blank `div`.

I'm filling that `div` with content dynamically, so the `div` height is growing constantly, I'm making a chat, and i want to detect if I am at the bottom of the div or in the last 10% of the `div` total height, If true, scroll to the bottom

```
var box = $('#page-content');
if (box.scrollTop() > (box.height*0.90))
    box.scrollTop(25000); // This is the top bottom
```

What I'm trying to do is, check if you are in the last 10% or less top bottom height of `"#page-content"` div (not when I'm reading "old messages" at the beginning of the Div), I have a function that appends new messages but I need to scroll down manually to see new messages...so i want to automatically scroll to the *New* bottom so i can see the new message :)

UPDATE:

```
function getChat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];
      html += '<span class="color-'+result.color+'"><b>'+result.usrname+'</b></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> '+result.chattext+'<br>';

      lastTimeID = result.id;     
    }
    $('#page-content').append(html);

    if(html!="")
    {   
     // Here i need to check if the scroll position is in the bottom or in the last 10%
     //then this to scroll to the top bottom (25000 is height limit)
     $('.page-content').scrollTop(25000);
    }

  }); }
```

Comment: please add your html of message. also your message append script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892217/jquery-scrolltop-not-scrolling-to-last-child i think exactly what u need

Comment: i've attached my function to get new messages, i just put 25000 there as a very large number that i will never get to that position cuz i have set a limit of X messages, that way i dont need to check "page-content" height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that inside the container for your messages (in your case the `#page-content` DIV), you can have an invisible placeholder `div` with some `id` set on to it.

In [***this demo JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/3qb46xfs/), as you click on the anchor `.addItem`, after the new item is added to the container, *the placeholder div is moved to the end of the container*. This ensures at the same time that clicking on the `.addItem` brings the *bottom* of the container DIV into view (*as it refers the `id` of the placeholder in its `href` attribute*).

```
function scrollToBottom(container) {
    // get all the child elements of the container
    var children = container.children('.item');

    // move the placeholder to the end of the container
    $('#contentBottom').insertAfter(children.eq(children.length - 1));
}
```

## Update

In order to determine your current scroll position, you should *listen* to `scroll` events in the `container`. Meanwhile, you should take into account the *updated* height value of the `container` when new messages arrive.

Check out [**this updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3qb46xfs/4/) in which I'm checking if the current scroll position is beyond 60 % from the top to easily see the effect.

***Note:*** If a new message comes when you are not scrolling, you can simply do `$('.container').scrollTop(25000)` in the same function/block of code that appends it to the `container`.

Comment: Understand, but what im trying to check is, when im in the top of the div "reading" old messages, it dont need to scroll down when i receive a new message...just scroll if im "waiting" for new message with the div scrolled down...just like every chat out there :P

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick in scrolling the page to bottom of `DIV`, i tried implementing it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt7n3tvv/).

See `$(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()` will always be equal to the total height(including paddings,margins) of children of the window, in our case it is equal to the `$('#page-content').height()+margin/padding`.

CSS:

```
div#page-content {
  height:600px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

in our situation:

```
$(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()=$('#page-content').height()+(margin/padding)=600px
```

so whenever we `scroll` it, we can attach an `scroll()` event to the `div` and easily check whether we are in in the last 10% or less top bottom height of "#page-content"

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){

   if($(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()>=($('#page-content').height()*(.9))){
     $(window).scrollTop($('#page-content').height()-$(window).height())
   }
})
```

Good luck.

Comment: hi, with your code my scroll is locked to the bottom :P and i cant scroll up

Comment: actually you can, try hard

Comment: thanks for your help, but no , i cant scroll up in my code, maybe cuz i dont have a Height set (as it is dynamic), is just a blank div without CSS params...i have attached my function where it all should happen, please take a look and how i can implement your solution there, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not make this, I don't want to take credit for it.

There is a jQuery plugin that makes anything that has a scroll bar scroll to a specific location or to an element. Since you want to scroll to a dynamic div, you can call this after you created the div and it will scroll to that location.

You can find the plugin over [here.](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

You can find a demo of the plugin in action over [here.](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Hope this was what you are looking for.

-W